# Angular2 - get ngFor to pass #item to constructed instance

Tags: angular

Lets say I have a list of data objects in the following form:

```
my_list = [
    {name:Alice, age:23},
    {name:Bill, age:33},
    {name:Clara, age:43}
];
```

I use `ngFor` to create a set of custom components based on the array:

```
<person-widget *ngFor="#item of my_list"></person-widget>
```

I want to give each created instance of `PersonWidget` access to the properties of the list item that spawned it, either by passing the `item` param into the instance as part of the `ngFor` or by giving the instance access to the original data somehow.

Basically, inside each `PersonWidget` class I want to be able to use `my_data_object.name` and get a value of `Alice` or `Bob` or `Clara`.

Any suggestions on how to do this or if there is a better, more "Angular2" way of doing this?

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a parameter of the `person-widget` component:

```
<person-widget *ngFor="#item of my_list" [item]="item"></person-widget>
```

The `person-widget` component must have defined this parameter, as described below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'person-widget',
  template: `
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  `
})
export class PersonWidgetComponent {
  @Input()
  item: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.item.name);
  }
}
```